# Javascript Split innerText and wrap with a Span

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the inner text of a header, then I would like to split the characters, then wrap each character in a span. I tried previously using insertBefore but I couldn't get it to work.

Here is my current code, which so far just logs each character.

```
// Title Split
const titleSplit = document.querySelectorAll('.title-split');

// Each El
Array.prototype.forEach.call(titleSplit, function(el, i) {

  let innerText = el.innerText;
  el.setAttribute('data-word', innerText);

  const chars = innerText.split('');

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(chars, function(el, i) {
    console.log(el);
  });
});
```

I specifically don't want any jQuery solutions. I'm trying to reverse learn Javascript to become more efficient. Any advise would be great. I tried putting in an insertBefore in the chars forEach but it just kept saying undefined.

Comment: Show us what caused the error, and exactly what the error was. Additionally, you don't need to hijack `Array.prototype.forEach` to iterate over HTML elements; nodes have their own, native `forEach` (you can chain it straight to your `querySelectorAll()` call.)

Comment: that Array.prototype.forEach.call really hurts my eye

Comment: Mind posting the HTML and expected result?

Comment: You mention you want to split/wrap characters, did you mean words?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map()` inside the `forEach()` loop to construct the result with span. Also I will recommend you not to use `innerText` as a variable name as it is property name which can lead to some confusion:

```js
// Title Split
const titleSplit = document.querySelectorAll('.title-split');

// Each El
Array.prototype.forEach.call(titleSplit, function(el, i) {

  let ElText = el.innerText;
  el.setAttribute('data-word', ElText);

  const chars = ElText.split('');

  var res = chars.map(function(el, i) {
    return `<span>${el}</span>`;
  }).join('');
  
  el.innerHTML = res;
  
});
```

```css
span{
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="title-split">Hello there</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelectorAll(...)` return a [`NodeList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList) which contains a method named [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach). So Instead of

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(titleSplit, function(el, i) {
   ...
}
```

You can just do

```
titleSplit.forEach(...);
```

Similarly, you can just do

```
chars.forEach(...);
```

because `chars` is an array and you can call `.forEach()` method on an array.

Now coming to your question, once you have the `chars` array, you can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method instead of `.forEach()`, to get a new array that contains strings where each character is wrapped by `span` tags.

```
const result = chars.map(c => `<span>${c}</span>`);
```

Finally, you need to iterate over the `result` array and insert its elements in the `DOM`.

```
result.forEach(el => document.body.append(el));
```

I have used `document.body` as the parent element of all the `span` elements. You can use any element that needs to be the parent element of all the `span` elements.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myHeader = querySelector('query my header please');
const spans = myHeader.innerText
  .split('')
  .map((char) => `<span>${char}</span>`)
  .join('');

document.querySelector('query element to put them').innerHTML = spans;
// OR
document.querySelector('query element to put them').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', spans);
// etc.
```